# Can my employer choose company I use for an eye test?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom

I work on computers and am therefore entitled to a free eye test. They recommend a local optician. I went to them last time, but wasn’t happy with the service, so for the next test I would like to use my normal optician.

Can the company refuse to pay for an eye test from a different company? 
The company I want to use is cheaper.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Ask your company, since they are paying for it?

Comment: They may have a special rate/contract with that optician and so may not be willing to pay a 3rd party.

Comment: @Dan I am going in the UK

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul they have said they will only pay if I use the company they have specified

Comment: Then there's your answer.

Comment: https://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/eye-tests.htm Legal obligations. Tl;dr, they don't have to let you choose.

Comment: @Studoku thank you - that was what I was looking for. I wasn’t sure if I could choose.

Comment: Wait what? You have to pay for eye tests?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, [your employer is allowed to stipulate what company you use for your eye test](https://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/eye-tests.htm):

> It's up to the employer how they provide the test. For example, they could let users arrange the tests and reimburse them for the cost later, **or they could send all their DSE users to one optician.**

However, that doesn't mean they'll necessarily refuse if you want to go to another optician. Your best bet is to ask and see.